# converting stack to 2d array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, stack

Is there a way to convert stack to 2d array?. I try using this code and I am getting this error

> [Error] cannot convert 'std::stack' to 'int' in assignment`

This is the code i try using

```
 int array[100][100];
   stack<int> myStack;
   
   for(int i=0;i < 100 ;i++)
   {
    for(int j=0;j < 100 ;j++)
    {
        array[i][j]=myStack;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Obviously, because you cannot assign `std::stack<int>` to `int`. What do you want to do?

Comment: It's not clear at all *how* you want to "convert" (it's more of a transformation than a conversion). How do the stack elements correspond to the matrix elements?

Comment: for example i have a stack  A with value of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0} . I want the value of stack to be in 2d array like this array[][] = {{1,2,3,4,5}{6,7,8,9,0}}.

Comment: `std::stack::pop()` to access elements from the stack. Add a counter to check current popped index to `i`,`j` row and column indices for your array. Why did you select a stack? It doesn't have any iterators, so by doing this you'll be destroying your stack essentially (so, make a copy before you start if required).

Comment: thank you for your answer @Roy2511 .But can you clarify and give a code example ? I use stack because it it was in my teacher instruction.